# Create shopify app that loads a script tag

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Is it possible to create a shopify app that loads a script tag on the store after it has been installed? I have a small functionality in a javascript file but I don't want my clients to add the script manually. They would just install the app from the shopify store and have the script automatically added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating a script tag is just an [api call](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/online_store/scripttag) so a proper Shopify app can do that but so can an external app where you get your customer to generate and give you a private app key/password pair.

Installing an app is easier for the customer but creating that app and shepherding it through the app store acceptance process is a fair bit of work for you.